# Using hardcoded passwords in an ETL process in Azure

Tags: azure, security, passwords, etl

I'm just learning so need your advice.
My company is using Data Bricks and Azure DevOps to create an ETL, and all logins and passwords in a configuration or other scripts is hardcoded. The sources are blob storages with excel or CSV's, or hiveDB's. Is this how this should be done? to hardcode all access inside the scripts?

Could anyone help me with a question, is this by the book?

Below examples how it looks like. Tried googling but Im not sure how to deal with this.

```
(6,'main','Sale_FCT',   'sql', 'sqlserver-xxx-launchpad-US-1', 'sqldb-xxx-launchpad-US-1', 'USadmin1', 'USadmin1'**,   1)


def f_read_from_sql(tab, uid="USadmin1", pwd_sc="USadmin1", url=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No, it is not by the book**.

This is exactly against all good practice. You should never hardcode secrets, regardless.
Especially when using Azure services, you have the possibility to integrate to a key vault - do it.
In both Databricks and Azure DevOps, you can secure the secrets - there is no good argument for hardcoding, unless you are looking to be insecure.

Read more here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Other relevant info:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/best-practices-index
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/security-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#dbutils-secrets
- https://github.com/Azure/AzureDatabricksBestPractices/blob/master/toc.md